# How to get subscription id programmatically in a Azure Role?

Tags: azure, role, azure-management-api

I have this Worker Role which makes use of REST Management API (through https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net), whose the most basic pre-requisite is the Subscription ID.

Is there a way to get the Subscription ID from a running (worker) role? E.g. say, through RoleEnvironment?

Comment: You can get throw Graph API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry Gatis, there is no way to get this via any method provided by Azure*.  You would need to pass this information into your role using something like the CSCFG configuration settings.

For a little more context - the subscription ID is only known at the RDFE layer.  Once you are in the Fabric layer (ie. your running Worker Role) then there is no concept of a subscription ID.  You can see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2011/05/05/windows-azure-role-architecture.aspx, process A and steps 1&2, for a little more info.

*If you are using AAD authentication for your Service Management API calls then you could get a list of all subscriptions for that AAD user using 'List Azure Subscriptions' - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn775050.aspx.  With those subscriptions you could enumerate all cloud services and match the deployment ID to the deployment ID for your worker role.

Edit: Typo in first paragraph.  Changed 'something like the Subscription ID' to 'something like the CSCFG configuration settings'.